# Nginx - Reverse proxy for 4 domain names, each pointing to different content

Tags: tomcat, nginx, proxy

I have four different domain names (we'll call them `aaa.com`, `aaa.co.za`, `bbb.com` and `bbb.co.za`). What I'm trying (and failing) to do is point both the `aaa` domains to regular old HTML content while both the `bbb` domains act as a reverse proxy to a tomcat server. As it stands the reverse proxy to tomcat works fine while I'm pointing all four the domains to it, the trouble starts once I try to update it to point half the domain names to different content. Keep in mind that I've only attempted changes on the file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` so all the examples you're about to see are in this file.

Here's what I currently have (which works fine):

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name 123.123.123.123;  # using fake IP for this question
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_pass http://bbb;  # this is the substitute for my actual url minus the .com/.co.za at the end
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location /phpmyadmin/ { }

  location /anextraproject/ { }
}
```

Notice that the above has some additional `location` statements, which successfully point to regular HTML/PHP resources by doing `bbb.com/anextraproject/`, for instance. I don't know how or why it works but it currently does, so if your answer could include preserving these extra `location`s or making it more efficient I'd really appreciate it.

Here's what I'm currently trying in order to split up the domain names (it doesn't work at all):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/htmlproject;
    index index.html index.html;

    server_name aaa.com www.aaa.com aaa.co.za www.aaa.co.za;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    server_name 123.123.123.123;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://bbb;
    }
}
```

Both the above `server` statements are in the same file, one after the other but when I try to run `sudo service nginx restart` I get the following in my error logs:

```
2017/12/31 15:14:39 [emerg] 42033#0: a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save.2:4
```

If I need to supply any additional info please let me know.

**EDIT:** The above error was caused by the `sites-enabled` directory also having multiple files called `default.save.1`, `default.save.2`, etc. After deleting them and restarting the server it didn't throw the error again but what's now happening is when I go to any of the domain names it directs me to `aaa`'s content so the second `server` statement in my second example above seems to be not working.

Comment: Your second server block only matches the host name `123.123.123.123`. Everything else (including `bbb.com`) will be handled by the default server.

Comment: Aah that did the trick, thank you! If you put your comment in an answer I'll accept it as the correct answer.